# Display dropdown menu on hover - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

**Simple problem: I have a nav menu, it shows sub menus when clicked on the '+' beside menu item. BUT IT SHOULD ALSO show drop down menu when hovered.**

I think the problem might be:

*a) Am I not targeting the right elements*

*b) is the toggle approach wrong?*

New to javascript so I am not sure what is the issue here.

I believe my script is wrong. not sure what the problem is, please help

```js
/* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */

// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".menu-test-container #primary-menu").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// Sub menu drop down
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
$(".dropdown-toggle").hover(function() {

  $(this).parent().find(".menu-test-container ul li .sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});
```

```css
/*
 # HEADER
 */

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.site-header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-navigation {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}


/*.menu-toggle, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul {
  display: none;
 }
*/


/* Menu styles */

.main-navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul,
.main-navigation ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* First Highrarchy */

.main-navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}


/*.dropdown-toggle:hover {
 display: block;
}

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <div class="site-branding-text">
      <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
    <div class="menu-test-container">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
        <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
                  <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
           <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
          </button>
                  <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                    <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
                      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
            </button>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
                          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
                          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
              </button>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
```

Comment: Answer to why it happens is pretty simple, when it is expanded it opens up and than the element position moves so you are no longer on the element.

Comment: I don't understand by "element position moves" ?

Comment: Put your mouse on the button. Click it, look where the button is now... Is it under the mouse?

Comment: Clicking the + opens up sub menus with its own buttons. not sure what you mean. i,e. each sub menu has drop down btn

Comment: Look at the button that you clicked. Where is it? Is it under your cursor still? Click the button for real in the snippet. Tell me what happens to that button.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean. so when i click the button, the ul moves out because the sub menu is being displayed...

Answer (score 1):

The menu only opens when hovering over the button. Hence, when even hovering over the menu itself, the menu closes. You can add the following

```
 $(".sub-menu").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("toggle-on");
});

$(".sub-menu").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("toggle-on");
});
```

The menu keeps jumping and causes UI changes since it is not absolute. You may add the following

```
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -26px;
  margin-left: -38px;
}
```

Below is an updated snippet.

```js
/* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */

// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".menu-test-container #primary-menu").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// Sub menu drop down
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
$(".dropdown-toggle").hover(function() {

  $(this).parent().find(".menu-test-container ul li .sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

$(".sub-menu").hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass("toggle-on");
});

$(".sub-menu").mouseleave(function() {

  $(this).removeClass("toggle-on");
});
```

```css
/*
 # HEADER
 */

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.site-header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-navigation {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}


/*.menu-toggle, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul {
  display: none;
 }
*/


/* Menu styles */

.main-navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul,
.main-navigation ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* First Highrarchy */

.main-navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-top: -26px;
  margin-left: -38px;
}


/*.dropdown-toggle:hover {
 display: block;
}

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <div class="site-branding-text">
      <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
    <div class="menu-test-container">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
        <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
                  <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
           <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
          </button>
                  <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
                    <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
                      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
            </button>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
                          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
                          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
              </button>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work when hovered over another menu items i.e. blog. and the sub sub menus don't show either